# Unreadable characters in a file on a remote server when viewing in a browser

Tags: file, text, unicode

I have to work with a text file on a remote server. The file can be accessed by a direct link using any browser, in the form http://server.school.com/files/people.all (not a real link, since the access requires a password). When I view it in Firefox some of characters are unreadable for example: 'JosĂ© Luis Paniagua SĂˇnchez'. I have a few questions.

1. Could the issue be caused by incorrect settings of my browser or could there be a problem with the file itself?
2. Is opening a file in a web browser and copying the entire content to a text editor using copy/paste inherently different from downloading the information with a script? Could it affect the encoding of the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select in the browser the encoding, UTF-8 likely. Firefox: View - Character Encoding. The problem is that the file does not specify the encoding of the file (or specifies a default encoding).

A binary download, like downloading an image file (with which you could try), should keep the file as-is.

Cut-copy-paste using the right encoding in the browser should work for UTF-8.

Assuming it is indeed UTF-8 (multibyte sequences for special chars), and you are working on Windows (which is single-byte), you'll better use a programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit, both free. They can set the encoding explicitly, and even convert.

Comment: Thanks. I used wget to download the file and it preserved the proper encoding.